# ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-call-graph - What are the various properties or methods in identity_context_data

Tags: identity, platform

ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-call-graph - What are the various properties or methods in identity_context_data ( i see username and authenticated ). How do i get user group with this module

Answer (score 0):

```
@property
def authenticated(self) -> bool:
    return self._authenticated

@authenticated.setter
def authenticated(self, value: bool) -> None:
    self._authenticated = value
    self.has_changed = True

@property
def username(self) -> str:
    return self._username

@username.setter
def username(self, value: str) -> None:
    self._username = value
    self.has_changed = True

@property
def token_cache(self) -> str:
    cache = SerializableTokenCache()
    if self._token_cache:
        cache.deserialize(self._token_cache)
    return cache

@token_cache.setter
def token_cache(self, value: SerializableTokenCache) -> None:
    if value.has_state_changed:
        self._token_cache = value.serialize()
        self.has_changed = True

@property
def state(self) -> str:
    return self._state

@state.setter
def state(self, value: str) -> None:
    self._state = value
    self.has_changed = True

@property
def nonce(self) -> str:
    return self._nonce

@nonce.setter
def nonce(self, value: str) -> None:
    self._nonce = value
    self.has_changed = True

# TODO: talk to MSIDWEB team
# or browse the code about how to implement the following:
@property
def last_used_b2c_policy(self) -> str:
    if len(self._last_used_b2c_policy):
        return self._last_used_b2c_policy.pop()
    return None

@last_used_b2c_policy.setter
def last_used_b2c_policy(self, value: str) -> None:
    self._last_used_b2c_policy = [value]
    self.has_changed = True

@property
def post_sign_in_url(self) -> str:
    return self._post_sign_in_url

@post_sign_in_url.setter
def post_sign_in_url(self, value: str) -> None:
    self._post_sign_in_url = value
    self.has_changed = True
```

ms_identity_web/context.py

Comment: _What does this code do?_ Read [answer] and [edit] your answer.

Comment: Hi @padaleiana, This code is half of the IdentityContextData class... u can see here all the methods that available in "identity_context_data" :)

Comment: How do I get the email id and token (tid) ?